# How to pass a NSMutableArray data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, uicollectionview

I need to pass data within an `NSMutableArray` but when I pass the data it works, but it is not correct. I need someone can explain about `NSMutableArray`. I use `UICollectionView` passing data to `UICollectionView`.

This is the code to pass the data:

Mainview.m:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *bookArray;
```

and

```
cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{.... 
 _databaseVersion = [[bookArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]bookVersion];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"course1"]){
            ShelfViewController *controller = (ShelfViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

            [controller setBookArray:bookArray]; //this one is work but not correct.
            controller.checkType = @"1";
            controller.statusMode = statusMode;
            controller.databaseVersion = _databaseVersion; // this one not work for Array
            controller.downloadFlag = @"0";
        }
```

When I get data from the main page, I need to go like this:

SeccondView.m:

```
datafromDatabase = [[_bookArray objectAtIndex:i]bookVersion];
```

but I already have

```
[[bookList objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]bookVersion]
```

and

```
numberOfItemsInSection:  ...return [booklist count]
```

I will explain my purpose now; I want to get data from a database in `mainview` and pass the array data to `Seccondview` to check with web service, but this code only works after the file is downloaded file. I can go to use like this:

```
[bookArray objectAtIndex:0]bookVersion]
```

but can work only after download I lost two day for this. Please guide me about passing data Array or guide me any Idea for check DB and webservice in `Seccondview.m`

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but looks to me you should use a MVC model, are you familiair with that? Otherwise this is maybe a good start: http://duo-lian.com/stanford-cs193p-part-2/